# Why my model accuracy is too low even while training for CIFAR10 dataset problem

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Keras 3 with pytorch 2.1 backend, I'm using cifar10 dataset and image classification problem, here is my code:

```py
import os

os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "torch"
import keras
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import (
    Dense,
    Flatten,
    Conv2D,
    MaxPooling2D,
    BatchNormalization,
    Activation,
    Dropout,
    Input,
    RandomFlip,
    RandomRotation,
    Rescaling,
)

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype("float32")
X_test = X_test.astype("float32")
Y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train, 10)
Y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_test, 10)
model = Sequential(
    layers=[
        Input(shape=X_train.shape[1:]),
        RandomFlip(),
        RandomRotation(factor=(-0.2, 0.2)),
        Rescaling(1.0 / 255),
        Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same"),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation("gelu"),
        Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same"),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation("gelu"),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Dropout(0.2),
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation("gelu"),
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation("gelu"),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Dropout(0.3),
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3)),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation("gelu"),
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3)),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation("gelu"),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Dropout(0.5),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(10, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()],
)
model.fit(
    X_train,
    Y_train,
    batch_size=50,
    epochs=20,
)
print("Evaluating")
model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
```

When running the above code, in the first epoch I'm getting categorical accuracy close to 0.1677 after 1000 steps, on second epoch it gets close to 0.2253, on fourth epoch it is 0.2555.

I tried changing learning_rate as well as beta_1 and beta_2 of Adam Optimizer.

I tried to use sparse categorical cross entropy with actual labels without one-hot encoding the labels but that didn't make too much a difference in accuracy.

I found questions about 0 accuracy, I used to have 0 accuracy when using `accuracy` instead of `categorical_accuracy` so 0 accuracy is not my problem anymore.

I found too many questions about accuracy low on evaluation but my accuracy is low even during training even from the first epoch, I don't face a problem high during training low during evaluation here, it's low everywhere.

I'm applying data augmentation as suggested by some posts, I changed code to use augmentation layer instead of `ImageDataGenerator` because the latter seems to be removed from keras 3(it was deprecated in keras 2 anyway). But the accuracy is still low.

I tried splitting validation data from my training data and supplying `validation_data` to `model.fit` method without success.

My python version is 3.11, my OS Is ArchLinux x64, I have NVIDIA driver not nouveau and cuda is enabled as verified by `torch.cuda.is_available()` (and I can see GPU Usage go to 100% when running the code). My NVIDIA Card is MX350 and CUDA version is 12.3.